# Get record where columntime greater than current time in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "user" and "userInfo" and i want to get all records of users
whose shop_openTime is greater than currentTime

Here is my first table "user"

```
id      name
1       xyz
2       abc
3       chd
4       yxb
```

Here is second table "userInfo"

```
id      userId      shop_openTime
1       1           10:00
2       2           09:00
3       3           11:00
4       4           08:00
```

How to get those users whose shopOpen time is greater than current time?

Answer (score -1):

This is SQL and not PHP related.

`SELECT user.id,user.name FROM user,userInfo WHERE user.id = userInfo.userId AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(userInfo.shop_openTIme) > NOW();`

Comment: should work
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: not working properly,means not working with ist timezone

Comment: you can try to convert it to your local time zone with CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)